# Should "filters" be included into sitemaps.xml?

Tags: seo, indexing, search-engine, sitemap

I have a list of entrys, for example

```
- Video 1
- Video 2
- (...)
- Video 1123
```

And they are shown 20 each page, so the page links are:

```
?page=1
?page=2
etc
```

However, there are filters that can be applied, such as:

```
- Language
- Length
- Quality
- Category
```

And the resulting links for the page selectors are:

```
?page=1&language=es
?page=2&language=es
?page=3&language=es
(...)
```

And so on for any of the filters avaiable.

My question is, should all those variant filters links be included into the sitemaps.xml considering the amount of links that would be generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of links in a sitemap is irrelevant as search engines support large sitemaps just fine as long as you follow their format properly.

You should include all URLs that produce unique content. Content split on to multiple pages is fine as well are different translations of content.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you. I personally get annoyed when these kinds of results come up in Google.

There is no limitation with Google other than no more than 50,000 links per sitemap.